# SQL Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure sp_product_listing, Line 0 Error converting data type varchar to datetime

Tags: sql-server

/*I'm new in SQL and I'm asked to create a procedure somehow procedure successfully created but when I try running the execute it didn't work.
    Can someone give me a hand please?*/

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_product_listing
(
@product varchar(40) ='%',
@month datetime,
@year datetime 
)
AS
SELECT
products.name AS product_name,
products.unit_price,
products.quantity_per_unit,
suppliers.name AS supplier_name
FROM products
INNER JOIN suppliers ON products.supplier_id=suppliers.supplier_id
INNER JOIN order_details ON products.product_id=order_details.product_id
INNER JOIN orders ON order_details.order_id=orders.order_id
WHERE products.name LIKE @product 
AND
@month=CONVERT(char(10),MONTH(orders.order_date))
AND
@year=CONVERT(char(10),YEAR(orders.order_date))
```

the run with an error
    when I run the execute 
    EXECUTE sp_product_listing
    'Jack',
    'June',
    '2001'

This is the error message I get

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure sp_product_listing, Line 0
>       Error converting data type varchar to datetime.

month and year are the one I'm stuck at.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this:

```
@month datetime,
@year datetime
```

Both parameters are declared as `datetime`, but a `datetime` variable holds complete date and time information (year, month, day, hour, minute, second...).

You are passing 'June' for the `@month` parameter, which doesn't work because 'June' is a `string` and `@month` is a `datetime`. That's what the error message says.

Comment: @Elgin Pass in a single datetime parameter, or two numerics (see my answer - sorry again for the formatting).

Comment: Thank you @Christian. Off to meta to see if any topics complain about formatting on a mobile device. Not fun.

Answer (score 2):

If your `order_date` column has an index, you are much better off using a range query over `MONTH()`, `DATEPART()`, etc. You can pass in the month/year combo as a single datetime, or you can simply change your parameters to integers as follows.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_product_listing
  @product VARCHAR(40) = '%',
  @year SMALLINT,
  @month TINYINT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @d SMALLDATETIME;

  SET @d = DATEADD(MONTH, @month - 1, 
    DATEADD(YEAR, @year-1900, '19000101'));

  SELECT ...
  WHERE Orders.order_date >= @d
    AND Orders.order_date < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @d);
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid filtering dates by parts as this will render indexes on date columns unusable. If you define @month and @year as varchars or ints you can construct a datetime range for entire month, and use this range to filter orders.order_date.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_product_listing
(
    @product varchar(40) ='%',
    @month varchar(10),
    @year varchar(4) 
)
AS
    declare @firstOfMonth datetime
    set @firstOfMonth = convert(datetime, @month + ' 1, ' + @year, 100)

    SELECT
    products.name AS product_name,
    products.unit_price,
    products.quantity_per_unit,
    suppliers.name AS supplier_name
    FROM products
    INNER JOIN suppliers ON products.supplier_id=suppliers.supplier_id
    INNER JOIN order_details ON products.product_id=order_details.product_id
    INNER JOIN orders ON order_details.order_id=orders.order_id
    WHERE products.name LIKE @product 
    AND
         orders.order_date >= @firstOfMonth
    AND  -- before first of next month
         orders.order_date < dateadd(m, 1, @firstOfMonth)
```

Comment: I still don't like passing in the string 'June' and all the promises that implies (which depend on regional and language settings being fixed).

Comment: ah...I need sometime to diguest it haha....I'm still really new at this.  And teacher asked us to run and test by using 'June' instead of numbers.....:(

Comment: haha and it's my project too *arg*
I figured using datename will work fine too but the teacher didn't teach anything about datename at all only told us about datepart,diff and add