# Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure sp_product_listing, Line 0 Error converting data type varchar to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, error-handling, varchar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure sp_product_listing, Line 0 Error converting data type varchar to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778381/sql-msg-8114-level-16-state-5-procedure-sp-product-listing-line-0-error-conv)

I've seen that this was asked a while ago by someone in another semester at my school, haha. But the answer they got didn't really satisfy me. Here is the link to the other question: [SQL Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure sp_product_listing, Line 0 Error converting data type varchar to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778381/sql-msg-8114-level-16-state-5-procedure-sp-product-listing-line-0-error-conv).

Most of what the answer says makes not much sense to me as I am very new to SQL. If we could open up another discussion on this, it would be great. Especially minus the teacher bashing that has been going on in my questions lately...

The following statement completes successfully, BUT:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_product_listing
(
     @product varchar(30),
     @month   datetime,
     @year    datetime
)
AS
  SELECT
     'product_name' = products.name,
     products.unit_price,
     products.quantity_in_stock,
     'supplier_name' = suppliers.name
  FROM
     suppliers
  INNER JOIN
     products ON suppliers.supplier_id = products.supplier_id
  INNER JOIN
     order_details ON products.product_id = order_details.product_id
  INNER JOIN
     orders ON order_details.order_id = orders.order_id
  WHERE
     products.name = @product 
     AND MONTH ('orders.order_date') = @month 
     AND YEAR ('orders.order_date') = @year;
GO
```

When I try and execute the procedure, I get an error message:

> *Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure sp_product_listing, Line 0
>
>   Error converting data type varchar to datetime.*

Here's how I execute the stored procedure:

```
EXECUTE sp_product_listing @product = 'Jack%', @month = 'June', @year = 2001;
GO
```

I've tried changing the two `datetime` datatypes to varchars and that has not worked because the column itself is `datetime` datatype originally. I'm not sure what I'm missing here?

UPDATE:

This was the final solution as guided by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1554034/valex.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_product_listing
(
   @product  varchar(30),
   @month    int,
   @year     int
)
AS
   SELECT               
      'product_name' = products.name,
      products.unit_price,
      products.quantity_in_stock,
      'supplier_name' = suppliers.name
   FROM
      suppliers
   INNER JOIN
      products ON suppliers.supplier_id = products.supplier_id
   INNER JOIN 
      order_details ON products.product_id = order_details.product_id
   INNER JOIN 
      orders ON order_details.order_id = orders.order_id
   WHERE
      products.name LIKE @product 
      AND MONTH (orders.order_date) = @month 
      AND YEAR (orders.order_date) = @year;
  GO
```

Also, for anyone still reading, here is the solution my teacher gave me which gives the same results.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_product_listing
(
@product    varchar(30),
@month      varchar(10),
@year       char(4)
)
AS
    SELECT
       'product_name' = products.name,
       products.unit_price,
       products.quantity_in_stock,
       'supplier_name' = suppliers.name
    FROM
       suppliers
    INNER JOIN
       products ON suppliers.supplier_id = products.supplier_id
    INNER JOIN
       order_details ON products.product_id = order_details.product_id
    INNER JOIN
       orders ON order_details.order_id = orders.order_id
    WHERE   
       products.name LIKE @product 
       AND DATENAME(MONTH,orders.order_date) = @month 
       AND YEAR (orders.order_date) = @year;
   GO
```

Comment: MONTH and YEAR both return integers. try making your parameters ints

Comment: As I stated above, I don't understand any of the answers given in the other question and because this is a school project, if I don't understand something, I can't use it... I'm sorry if that wasn't obvious in the description.

Comment: As a side-note: [Microsoft recommends that you **avoid** the `sp_` prefix for your own stored procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214379%28v=sql.80%29.aspx); that prefix is reserved for Microsoft's future use. Also, using the `sp_` prefix has [negative performance impacts on your procedures](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/stored-procedure-performance-using-%E2%80%9Csp_%E2%80%9D-prefix-%E2%80%93-myth-or-fact/) - just **don't do it**.

Comment: If you don't understand the suggestions in the other question, what makes you think you will understand the suggestions in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because of 'June' is not a `DATEIME` value and [MONTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) function returns `int`. Also if you input @product as a MASK (with '%') you should use `LIKE` instead of `=` So you should declare your procedure as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE    sp_product_listing
(
@product    varchar(30),
@month      int,
@year       int
)

....
WHERE               products.name LIKE @product AND
....
```

And call it

```
EXECUTE             sp_product_listing @product = 'Jack%', @month = 6, @year = 2001;
```

Comment: I tried that but got this error: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_product_listing, Line 8 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Why do you call `MONTH ('orders.order_date')` with `'` just use  `MONTH (orders.order_date)`. In your case MONTH tries to convert STRING `'orders.order_date'` to date.

Comment: OMG that was it. Jeeeeeeze SQL can be finnicky hey! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be a number of problems here.

I assume the column `orders.order_date` is of type `datetime`. Therefore the result of the functions `MONTH (orders.order_date)` and `YEAR (orders.order_date)` will be integers.

This means that if you want the lines

```
MONTH (orders.order_date) = @month AND
YEAR (orders.order_date) = @year;
```

to work meaningfully, your parameters `@month` and `@year` should really be integers.

On top of this, it looks like you're passing in @product with a wildcard that only makes sense for `LIKE`, not `=` in the where clause.

And finally, not sure why you are quoting `'orders.order_date'` in the function invocations - I don't think the quoting is necessary.

I suggest you make this change:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE    sp_product_listing
(
@product    varchar(30),
@month      int,
@year       int
)
AS
...
WHERE       products.name LIKE @product
...
            MONTH (orders.order_date) = @month AND
            YEAR (orders.order_date) = @year;
```

and call `EXEC` as follows:

```
EXECUTE sp_product_listing @product = 'Jack%', @month = 6, @year = 2001;
GO
```

Notwithstanding the above, and in regards to the immediate error you are getting:

In the procedure definition, they are defined as being of type `datetime`, which means when calling the procedure, the SQL engine will expect to receive `datetime` values for them.

In addition to this, the way you are running `EXEC`, you are trying to pass in values to `@month` and `@year` that represent just the month and year components of a date (respectively), whereas the SQL engine is expecting valid (i.e. complete) dates.

The error you are getting is simply the SQL engine complaining that it can't interpret your input value `'June'` as a valid, complete date (and the same for trying to interpret `2001` as a valid, complete date)

Comment: Okay so what should I do instead? I've been working on this for hours and hours.

Comment: @isolatedhowl - please see latest edit for a suggestion of what to change.